# Slowing down Selenium in Node

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've just began learning Selenium with Node to automate my UI.

I have the following script (which works perfectly)
However, I am wanting the statements to each execute one after another at a slower time (at the moment it is super fast).
How do I do this?

```
const By = selenium.By;
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/a[1]")).click();
const firstName = driver.findElement(By.id("firstName"));
firstName.sendKeys("Jon");
const lastName = driver.findElement(By.id("lastName"));
lastName.sendKeys("Smith");
```

Answer (score 2):

In simple words *slowing down the speed* of the *Program Execution* defeats the purpose of *Test Automation*. The main objective of *Test Automation* is to speed up the execution of repetitive task of *Manual Validation*. Hence trying to slow down the speed of execution will defeat the main purpose of *Test Automation*.

Having said that, it is worth to mention moving forward you have to face certain situation where you have to synchronize the fast moving *WebDriver* instance with the lagging *Web Client* instance. In those cases you have to induce *waits* in the form of [Implicit Waits](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) and [Explicit Waits](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) i.e. [WebDriverWait](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) pertaining to [WebElementCondition](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElementCondition.html)

Hence **Slowing down Selenium in Node** would be against all *best practices* and must be avoided.

Comment: At the speed though, you are unable to see what is happening. I read about the idea of .wait option, I'm just unsure how to implement.

Comment: @CharlieHoward Don't worry about waits right now till you require it. Keep automating the testcases. If you hit any roadblock raise a question here. SO volunteers will be happy to help you out. All the best.

Comment: @CharlieHoward If my Answer have catered to your question please Accept the Answer by clicking on the tick mark beside my Answer which is just below the Votedown arrow so the tick mark turns green.

Comment: @CharlieHoward Why do you want to see what is happening? What do you want to wait for?